# Can you set an FM oscillator as the modulation source for another FM oscillator?

Tags: audiokit

I'm new to both AudioKit and stack overflow, sorry if I'm not asking this in the correct way.

I'm trying to figure out how to modulate the frequency of one AKFMOscillator with the output of another oscillator, so that they would work more like the operators of an FM synth. If I understand correctly
, AKFMOscillators have their own built in modulation source, but I'd like to be able to stack multiple modulators so that I can set up algorithms like on an FM synth, however nothing I've tried so far works. 
I've gotten some results doing this:

```
var oscillatorOne = AKFMOscillator()
var oscillatorTwo = AKFMOscillator()
oscillatorOne.modulatingMultiplier = oscillatorTwo
```

but that's not really doing the right thing. Is this even possible? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: someone else asked something very similar a few weeks ago, which I've provided an answer with a working example which can be useful for you, you can find it here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801986/audiokit-how-to-perform-frequency-modulation-for-akplayer/61808276#61808276 )

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to play around with that code but it does indeed look like it might solve my problem. I don't currently have voting privileges, and I'm embarrassed to admit I can't figure out how to mark this as answered, but thanks for the help!

Comment: You wouldn't because I left a comment instead of an answer. You can otherwise vote my answer in the thread I have shared, thanks!